# Jquery and laravel 404 not found

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

Hey I am new at laravel and I am making an autocomplete search bar. But I am having problem that is when I write any word it gives error in my console panel that is

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
```

the line on which this error is coming in jquery is

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

Please help me. I have already tried alot but failed to get the required result.

View of my code where I included jquery is

```
  <html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
 <body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col col-md-4">
      <section class="card">
         <header class="card-heading">
             <input type="text" name="searchname" class="form-control" id="searchname" placeholder="Search"  >
          </header>
          <div class="card-block">
            <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>ID</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="id" class="form-control"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Symtomps</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="symtomps" class="form-control" ></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

          </div>
       </section>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('#searchname').autocomplete({
    source: '{!!URL::route('autocomplete')!!}',
    //source: '{{ asset('search') }}',
    //source: '{{URL::route('autocomplete')}',
    minlength:1,
    autoFocus:true,
    select:function(e,ui){
    //$('#id').val($data->symtomps);
}
});

</script>
```

Controller of my code is

```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;


   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\Disease;
   use Input;

   class DiseaseController extends Controller
    {
 public function index()
 {
     return view('disease.disease');
 }
public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{
   $term = $request->term;
    $data = Disease::where('symtomps','Like','%'.$term.'%')
    ->take(2)
    ->get();
    $result=array();

    foreach($data as $key => $v)
    {
        $results[]=['id' =>$v->id,'value'=>$v->symtomps];
    }
    return response()->json($results);
}
```

}

Comment: share code where you include "jquery.js" ?

Comment: @user2486 shared my code

Comment: Are you sure you have folder name `code.jquery.com` at root and have query file there?

Comment: @M_Idrees I have used cdn of jquery file

Comment: Its hard to suggest without debugging. Lets try put echo for `"{!!  URL::route('autocomplete')  !!}"` and see if it is returning correct accessible path, also replace source property with some hard-coded array items like `var items = [
      "item1",
      "item2"
 ]; ` and then `source:items,` and check if it works in this simpler form?

Comment: @M_Idrees its working fine with the option you told but i have to fetch data from database and then i have to show the list

Comment: Ok. and what is the result of echo statement for route/path ?

Comment: @M_Idrees it returns this http://localhost/TestProject/public/autocomplete

Comment: If you try visit this link in browser, can you get result successfully?

Comment: @M_Idrees it gives me notfoundHTTPException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154621/discussion-between-m-idrees-and-nida-akram).

Answer (score 0):

You have not resource (means not any store file like json) either use ajax or do like this.

```
source: function (request, response) {
    $.get("{!!  URL::route('autocomplete')  !!}", {
        query: request.term
    }, function (data) {
        response(data);
    });
},
```

Comment: which quotes should i change their are two quotes in this line

Comment: Change as I given

Comment: Still giving the error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /TestProject/public/autocomplete?term=t

Comment: Do you have route `autocomplete` or `/autocomplete` ?

Comment: yes i have this is my route Route::get('/autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'DiseaseController@autocomplete'));

Comment: Did you try `"{!!  url('/autocomplete')  !!}"` ?

Comment: yes its giving error route /autocomplete not defined

Comment: @NidaAkram : you are not using resource, use ajax for this. or use as I updated my ans.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154581/discussion-between-nida-akram-and-user2486).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery from CDN, then you have to specify complete link in correct format.

Try changing your lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: still errors are coming in my console             /TestProject/public/autocomplete?query=t Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)